# How to make validation on datepicker in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make validation on datepicker such as if a user does not select an date and it gives an errors.for instance "date is required"

Comment: Please go through the Vue documentation given here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: I did that but i didn't find sufficient remedy for it.. basically, I wanted to display error message in date-picker like if user does not select date and press submit button.

Comment: Bind a variable on to the datepicker and check if the value is empty or not when you submit the form. Have a variable/computed property to determine whether the error `div` has to be displayed or not. Reset this property when you initiate form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the v-model to validate the date.

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      date: null
    },
    components: {
      vuejsDatepicker
    },
    methods: {
      formSubmit() {
        if (!this.date) {
          alert('Please select a date');
          return;
        }
        console.clear();
        console.log('Selected date is ' + this.date);
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <vuejs-datepicker v-model=date :typeable=true>
  </vuejs-datepicker>
  <input type="submit" v-on:click="formSubmit">

</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts.  actually i want the message and date input field should be red when user click upon submit button without date selection.

Answer (score 0):

You could add required in date picker

```
<vuejs-datepicker v-model=date :typeable=true required>
  </vuejs-datepicker>
```

This will add a red border around the datepicker.